# Modify and append pandas dataframe inside loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have ~40 csv files that are snapshots of real estate listings online in a point of time. I am trying to consolidate these into one csv file, while at the same time specify when a real estate listing is posted and when they are taken down (i.e. if the listing is new, add it to the end of the csv file, if it existed before update the "last seen" column with latest date - while retaining the date it was posted in a separate column).

I have two things I would like to ask for help on:

1) the loop I have written only sees the "initial" IDs and does not search through the "newly added" listings to update their "last seen" date (i.e. after a listing is not in the initial batch, they are all seen as "new" even if they were in the previous csv file added to the consolidated master) - how do I update the dataframe so that in each loop it compares the new csv file with the latest master dataframe?

2) It seems like my code is very inefficient as it takes ~20 min to run through - can I make it more efficient?

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta, date
import os

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

#Define what date range to consolidate
start_date = date(2017, 8, 1)
end_date = date.today()

#Create a starting dataframe with the first csv file and change the "hash_id" to string to prepare dataframe for insertions using this as the unique identifier for each listing

master_df = pd.read_csv("real_estate(" + start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + ").csv")
master_df = master_df.assign(last_seen=master_df['date'])
master_df['hash_id'] = master_df['hash_id'].astype(str)

#Loop through all CSV files for the time period listed, if listing is already in dataframe then update the "last seen" with the newer date, otherwise add the listing as a new row to the master dataframe

for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    file_path = "real_estate(" + single_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + ").csv"
    print(single_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
    if os.path.isfile(file_path) is True and os.path.getsize(file_path) > 1:
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        temp_df = temp_df.assign(last_seen=temp_df['date'])
        for index, row in temp_df.iterrows():
            hash_id = str(row['hash_id'])
            if master_df['hash_id'].str.contains(hash_id).any():
                master_df.loc[master_df['hash_id'] == hash_id, 'last_seen'] = row['date']
            else:
                master_df.loc[len(master_df)] = row

#write the consolidated dataframe to CSV
master_df.to_csv("master_file.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem correct you can just read in the hole dataframe as one and then use transform to find the last date corresponding to each hash and then drop duplicates of hash and keep the first entry.

```
df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv("real_estate(" + date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + ").csv")
    for date in daterange(start_date, end_date)
    ])

df = df.sort_values('date')
df['last_seen'] = df.groupby('hash_id')['date'].transform('last')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='hash_id', keep='first')
```

Comment: Thanks for this, seems like a really elegant solution. Apologies for forgotting to mention, but I also have a column "date" which shows when it was first seen - I want to calculate how long a posting is online. Is there a possibility to adapt your solution to also retain the "first seen" and "last seen" of each post at the same time?

Comment: After you dropped the duplicates of hash_id the date column should resemble the first time a listing was in the data. The difference between "first seen" and "last seen" shoudl just be the difference between the column date and last_seen. Or am I missing something here?